# Trying to connect to Mssql server via knex

Tags: sql-server, node.js, knex.js

I'm trying to connect to a remote database with knex but I get this error:
"tedious deprecated The default value for `options.encrypt` will change from `false` to `true`. Please pass `false` explicitly if you want to retain current behaviour. at node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:212:23
Unhandled rejection ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 151.80.119.227,14831:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 151.80.119.227,14831"

I can connect via Microsoft sql server management studio with same host, user, password so I'm lost.

Edit:
This is how I create my knex var:

```
 var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'mssql',
  connection: {
    server : '151.80.119.227,14831',
    user : '****',
    password : '****',
    database : '****'
  }
});
```

I can connect to it via python with:

```
 con = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};server=151.80.119.227,14831;database=*****;uid=****;pwd=****")
```

So why won't it connect through node.js ....

Comment: Check your sql server error logs for login attempts. That will give you some insights. If there are no entries, your attempt isnt making it to the server. If there are attempts, you will see the error message and you can go from there.

Comment: @dfundako 
I don't have access to those, I have read only access to a test database. Since I have no problems connecting with Python is it "tedious" that's the problem? I read some old posts about tedious messing up when there are uppercase letters in database name, and the db I'm trying to connect to has those.

Comment: I guess if the port is `14831` try to replace comma separating IP and port with a colon `server : '151.80.119.227:14831',`

Answer (score 11):

Port should actually be specified in the MSSQL options variable:

```
 var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'mssql',
  connection: {
    server : '151.80.119.227',
    user : '****',
    password : '****',
    database : '****',
    options: {
      port: 14831
    }
  }
});
```

This is from reading the code at https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/v0.16.2/src/dialects/mssql/index.js

Answer (score 2):

port for node-mssql driver should be set like this:

```
{
  dialect: 'mssql',
  connection: {
    user: "sa",
    password: "S0meVeryHardPassword",
    server: "151.80.119.227",
    port: 14831,
    database: "knex_test"
  }
}
```