# Unable to connect Sql server using knex

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, knex.js

I am using `Knex.js` to connect `Sql server` using `Node.js`. Here is what i tried so far

1. `npm init`
2. `npm install knex --save`
3. `npm install mssql -g`
4. `nodemon index.js`

and `index.js` file have

```
 var knex = require('knex')({  
 client: 'mssql',  
 connection: {  
  user: 'sa',  
  password: 'Password@123',  
  server: 'manikant/SQLEXPRESS',  
  database: 'myDb' ,
  options: {
    port: 1433
   } 
  }  
}); 

  app.get('/getData',(req,res)=>{
   const data = {};
   knex.select("*").from("usr")  
   .then(function (depts){  
   depts.forEach((dept)=>{ //use of Arrow Function  
    console.log({...dept}); 
    data = {dept}
     });  
   }).catch(function(err) {  
    console.log(err);  
   }).finally(function() {  
   knex.destroy();  
   });  
  res.json({data})

 })
```

But getting errors `message: 'Failed to connect to manikant/SQLEXPRESS:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND manikant/SQLEXPRESS',
    code: 'ESOCKET'
  },`

`TCP/IP` protocol is enabled on port `1433` and `Sql server browser` is running.
[followed similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577248/node-js-mssql-tedius-connectionerror-failed-to-connect-to-localhost1433-conn) 
**Note:-** Able to connect with java application.So seems like problem with knex only.

Comment: [Possible duplicate of]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857977/trying-to-connect-to-mssql-server-via-knex

Comment: @ErenYatkin not duplicate with existing one as i have already specified `port option`